# Too few positionals passed, why?

Tags: raku

```
sub hanoi(Int:D $n, Str:D $start, Str:D $end, Str:D $extra,
          &move_disk:(Int:D, Str:D, Str:D --> Nil)
          --> Nil)
{
    if $n == 1 {
        move_disk(1, $start, $end);              # Step 1
    }
    else {
        hanoi($n - 1, $start, $extra, $end);     # Step 2
        move_disk($n, $start, $end);             # Step 3
        hanoi($n - 1, $extra, $end, $start);     # Step 4
    }
}

sub print_instruction(Int:D $n, Str:D $start, Str:D $end --> Nil)
{
    say "Move disk #$n from $start to $end";
}
```

Calling `hanoi(3, 'A', 'B', 'C', print_instruction)` gives:

```
Too few positionals passed; expected 3 arguments but got 0
  in sub print_instruction at <unknown file> line 15
  in block <unit> at <unknown file>
```

Comment: `print_instruction` in `hanoi(3, 'A', 'B', 'C', print_instruction)` *calls* `print_instruction` instead of referring to it like in Python. (Why? Too many good reasons to fit in comments but one is that Raku unifies field references and method calls -- both are `.bar` -- as part of 100% encapsulation of object state. That [solves the Fragile base class problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class#:~:text=One%20possible,superclass%20states.) and makes Raku [Actor model "ready"](https://gist.github.com/raiph/849a4a9d8875542fb86df2b2eda89296#:~:text=Actor%20model%20%22consistent%22).)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code:

1. `hanoi(3, 'A', 'B', 'C', print_instruction)`

In that statement, you're passing the **result** of the call to `print_instruction` as the 4th parameter.  You're evidently expecting it to be something `Callable`judging from the signature of the `hanoi` sub.  If you want to pass the callable, you need to prefix the name with a `&`, so:

```
hanoi(3, 'A', 'B', 'C', &print_instruction);
```

Because the `print_instruction` sub does expect 3 arguments, and you called it with zero, you get the "expected 3 arguments but got 0" error.

2. The first call to `hanoi` has 5 arguments, but the recursive calls only pass 4.  You will get a similar error there, but with different numbers: expected 5 arguments but got 4.  The simplest solution is to pass that on as well:

   hanoi($n - 1, $start, $extra, $end, &move_disk);

Finally: using underscores in identifiers is *sooo* 1990's  :-)   You can also use the hyphen in identifiers in the Raku Programming Language!  So you can call the `move_disk` subroutine `move-disk`  :-)

Comment: so maybe camelCase, snake_case and hyena-case? (which I prefer to kebab-case due to my liking for animals)

Comment: hyena-case?  I don't get it :-)